# Mathematical set library/header

Tags: c++, set

In what library/header (if any) is mathematical set defined? I need set to have functions like intersection, union etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `<set>` and `<algorithm>`.

Then the std provides `std::set_union`, `std::set_intersection` and so on.

example:

```
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>

 ...
std::set<int> s1, s2;
for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)  s1.insert(i);
for(int i = 10; i < 30; ++i) s2.insert(i);
std::set<int> my_union, my_intersection;
std::set_union(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end(), std::inserter(my_union, my_union.begin()));
std::set_interesction(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end(), std::inserter(my_intersection, my_intersection.begin()));
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`std::set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/) (`<set>`) for the set and [`std::set_intersection`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/) and [`std::set_union`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_union/) (`<algorithm>`) for this.

Comment: IIRC there are some differences between a set in C++ and a mathematical set, I think objects in a set in C++ are somehow ordered while there is no order defined in a math set.

Comment: Yes. Then you can use `std::unordered_set`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [std::set](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/set.html). You can use algorithms such as [set_intersection](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/) on it.

Answer (score 2):

Search `<algorithm>` header for functions

```
· set_difference
· set_intersection
· set_symmetric_difference
· set_union
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the following on top of your code

```
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
```

Comment: Benoit said this already in 2011, plus he added a lot more details and explanations.

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://github.com/aseprano/Set, it provides the things you are looking for. Do not use std::set or any other stl container in that they does not have full support to math sets.